# Load alternate page content into div onload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My project is a team website on a LAMP server.  Included are several "team pages" for different age levels.  I'm trying to include "external" content (that is, from another page on my domain" into a specific div.  I've been able to use an iframe successfully, but the result is not responsive, and is honestly, quite ugly.

I've found examples for calling AJAX content with clicks or other actions, however I really just need the content to be there on load.

At the risk of being too verbose, the reason I am trying to load this content externally is that the content is relevant to multiple sub-pages.  Since it is not static content (essentially, a simple slider with blog posts), I want to have a common source file that can be updated and have pages include it automatically.

At the moment, I have the code for this carousel redundantly in each team's page.  While it's not necessarily a deal-breaker, it just seems so counter-intuitive to have to update 7 different pages individually, rather than updating one block of code that can be called into the team pages.

Surely, I'm missing something simple...  any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language is your website written in? Is it a simple collection of php pages? html only? Are you using a specific framework? More details are welcome :)

Comment: Thank you!  Site is HTML5.  [http://warminsterpioneers.org/football-65.html]

Comment: The content I'd like to make available remotely is "Recent Posts"

` <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

       var ocPosts = $("#oc-posts");

       ocPosts.owlCarousel({
        margin: 20,
        nav: true,
        navText: ['<i class="icon-angle-left"></i>','<i class="icon-angle-right"></i>'],
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        dots: false,
        responsive:{
         0:{ items:1 },
         600:{ items:2 },
         1000:{ items:3 },
         1200:{ items:4 }
        }
       });

      });

     </script>`

Answer (score 1):

It should be rather simple using [jQuery's load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/). I was able to get an html file loading the contents of another html file on my local server doing the following:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="loadedContent" />
    </body>
    <script>
        $('#loadedContent').load("contentToLoad.html"); <!-- loads other page's content -->
    </script>
</html>
```

contentToLoad.html:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

It loads the contentToLoad.html's content into my index.html onload without a problem

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#elementId').load('/partial/filename.html')
```

Look at jQuery's load function. Allows you to make an ajax call to pull html from external source and load it to an element. (same origin rules still apply)

Other option is to use jQuery's ajax function. Upon success load the element with the returned data.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
       url: "/partial/filename.html",
       type: "get",
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(data){
         $('#elementId').html(data);
       }
    });
```

**Depending on the data you are loading you may want to use dataType text or html.**

> "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated
>   when inserted in the DOM.
>
> "text": A plain text string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database you can query the data you want and output it with the rest of the page. If that's not an option, you can run this jquery onload, it doesn't have to involve an event like a click.  Without seeing your code it's difficult to provide a more complete answer.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "/pathtoajaxfile.php",
       type: "get",
       dataType: "html",
       data: {"id" : "somepageid"},
       success: function(data){
         $("#myDiv").html(data);
       },
       error: function(e){
         alert(e);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you're on a LAMP server.  If your pages are PHP, you could make a file containing the content you'd like to use and include it in the various places where you like to have it.  Be careful about paths to content - depending on where you are in your site, your paths may change.  The solution for this is for your "recycled" content to use absolute paths to the resources it needs.